# How to merge two dataframes based on header and columns values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes. The first one contains the data of different cities.

```
dfTmp:
    City        2005    2007    
0   London       3       7
1   Paris        2       0
```

then an *empty* dataframe that I want to populate

```
dfData:
    City        Year        
0   London      2005     
1   London      2007     
2   Paris       2005         
3   Paris       2007
```

I want to merge the two datasets. Then `dfData` should become as the following

```
dfData:
    City        Year    Value   
0   London      2005     3
1   London      2007     7  
2   Paris       2005     2      
3   Paris       2007     0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the second dataframe, dfData.  All the data you need is in the dfTmp.  You just need to reshape dfTmp using the following:

## Option 1

#### using `set_index` and `stack`

```
dfData = dftmp.rename_axis('Year', 1).set_index('City').stack().reset_index(name='Value')

print(dfData)
```

Output:

```
     City  Year  Value
0  London  2005      3
1  London  2007      7
2   Paris  2005      2
3   Paris  2007      0
```

## Option 2

#### using `melt`:

```
dfData = dftmp.melt(id_vars='City', var_name='Year', value_name='Value')

print(dfData)
```

Output:

```
     City  Year  Value
0  London  2005      3
1   Paris  2005      2
2  London  2007      7
3   Paris  2007      0
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution given above, - avoiding merge using only dfTmp -, seems optimal.
In case you insist to use Merge, the following could be done:

First take care that the Pandas package is imported:

```
import pandas as pd
```

We have the following data:

```
Tmp = {'City': ['London', 'Paris'],
    '2005': [3,2],
   '2007': [7,0]}
dfTmp = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['City', '2005', '2007'])
```

And:

```
data = {'City': ['London', 'London', 'Paris', 'Paris'],
    'Year': [2005,2007, 2005, 2007]}
dfData = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['City', 'Year'])
```

Then use Merge in Pandas:

```
dfNew = pd.merge(dfData, dfTmp)
dfNew.iloc[0:4,0:3]
```